# Is Python also divided into LTS and stable versions?

Tags: python

Does Long-term surppot version and stable version exist in Python 2.x or Python 3.x version? And if so, what are the criteria?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

not currently

see PEP407 status: "deferred"

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0407/

Comment: A subtle description would have been greate. I always loved devs simple explanations on this site.@litepresence

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't use same wording but on 7. November, 2019 [PEP602](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0602/) was accepted which introduced release cycles. You can find more info about current versions and their states [here](https://devguide.python.org/versions/#versions).